# Three consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence have a sum of 36 and a product of 1428. Find three terms.

Tags: arithmetic

Now I already know the answer to that you have to do this first

$3x=36$

And then the rest you are just subbing in, but why do you have to divide 36 by 3. I am confused.

Comment: You can represent the terms as $a-r$, $a$ and $a+r$. Then the sum is given by $3a= 36 \implies a = 12$. For the product, you have $(a-r) \times a \times (a+r) = 1428 \implies (a^2 - r^2) \times a = 1428$. Since the value of $a$ is now known, this can easily be solved.

Comment: Presumably $x$ is the *middle* term, i.e., $(x-d)+x+(x+d)=36$, so the rest is $(x-d)x(x+d)=1428$. The trick is to solve these two equations for the two unknowns, $x$ and $d$.

Comment: The first thing you should do is define $x$, then you should explain why $3x=36$.  When you do that, dividing by $3$ is the way to solve your equation.

Answer (score 1):

The [sum of an arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) with an odd number of terms

is the middle term times the number of terms:

$\Sigma = n \dfrac{a_1+a_n}2.$

In this example, $36=3x$.

Comment: ... if there are an odd number of terms

Comment: Nice approach. I wouldn’t have known there’s another way other than solving a system involving the common ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The three terms can be written $x-d$, $x$, $x+d$.  Then

$$(x-d)+x+(x+d) = 3x =36.$$

Since $3$ times $x$ is $36$, divide both sides by $3$ to get $x=12$.  Now the three terms are $12-d$, $12$, and $12+d$.  Multiply them together to get

$$(12-d)(12)(12+d) = 1428.$$

Divide both sides by $12$ and the remaining equation gives you $d$.  Then you can get all three terms.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
a+(a+d)+(a+2d)&=36\\
3a+3d&=36\\
a+d&=12
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can let the 3 numbers be $(x, x-y, x+y)$ if we take the sum we see

\begin{align}
(x-y)+x+(x+y) &= 36\\3x&=36\\x&=12
\end{align}
solving product equation gives you

\begin{align}
(12-y)(12+y)*12&=1428\\(12^2 - y^2)&=119\\144-119&=y^2\\y=\pm5\end{align}
we can use any value of y because of the way we have written the 3 numbers in the beginning.